# Linking OpenBLAS and Armadillo with CodeBlocks project

Tags: c++, codeblocks, armadillo, openblas

I am using Armadillo along with OpenBLAS for linear algebraic operations. For a sample code I am linking these libraries using following commands:

```
 g++ sample.cpp -I "path\armadillo\include" -I "path\OpenBLAS\include" -L "path\OpenBLAS\lib" -llibopenblas
```

The code is compiled and runs successfully. Therefore, to link these libraries with CodeBlocks I used Linker setting and Search Directories option to specify location for libraries. But I am getting following errors:

```
path\OpenBLAS\lib\libopenblas.a(dormqr.o):dormqr.f|| undefined reference to `_gfortran_concat_string'|
```

Is this related with linking libraries or with compiler?

Comment: This sounds like a linker error.  I googled _gfortran_concat_string and there seem to be solutions to this issue.

Comment: The error is with linking gfortran with the project. I linked libgfortran.a file but I am now getting other errors: undefined reference to `signbitq' and undefined reference to `finiteq'

Comment: I assume those are from the math library.  Look at the documentation to see which dependent libraries you need to add.  Also, remember, their order matters.